# NHibernate - TransformUsing.SingleOrDefault return default value

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I have a problem with NHibernate

My mapping :

```
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2">
  <class name="StatsRow" table="StatsRow" lazy="true">
    <id name="StatsRowId" column="StatsRow_Id" type="int">
      <generator class="native" >
        <param name="sequence">SEQ_StatsRow</param>
      </generator>
    </id>
    <property name="JobId" column="JobId" type="string" not-null="true" />
    <property name="CreationTime" column="CreationTime" type="DateTime" not-null="true" />
    <property name="WorkflowName" column="WorkflowName" type="string" not-null="true"/>
    <property name="JobState" column="JobState" type="string" not-null="true" />
    <property name="LastErrorCode" column="LastErrorCode" type="string" not-null="true" />
    <property name="LastErrorMessage" column="LastErrorMessage" type="string" not-null="false" />
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

My class StatsRow :

```
[Serializable]
internal class StatsRow
{
    protected int _statsrowid;
    protected string _jobid;
    protected DateTime _creationtime;
    protected string _workflowname;
    protected string _jobstate;
    protected string _lasterrorcode;
    protected string _lasterrormessage;

    public DocFactoryStatsRow() { }

    public virtual int StatsRowId
    {
        get { return _statsrowid; }
        set { _statsrowid = value; }
    }
    public virtual string JobId
    {
        get { return _jobid; }
        set { _jobid = value; }
    }
    public virtual DateTime CreationTime
    {
        get { return _creationtime; }
        set { _creationtime = value; }
    }
    public virtual string WorkflowName
    {
        get { return _workflowname; }
        set
        {
            if (value != null && value.Length > 200)
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("value", value.ToString(), "WorkflowName cannot contain more than 200 characters");
            _workflowname = value;
        }
    }
    public virtual string JobState
    {
        get { return _jobstate; }
        set
        {
            if (value != null && value.Length > 32)
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("value", value.ToString(), "JobState cannot contain more than 32 characters");
            _jobstate = value;
        }
    }
    public virtual string LastErrorCode
    {
        get { return _lasterrorcode; }
        set
        {
            if (value != null && value.Length > 64)
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("value", value.ToString(), "LastErrorCode cannot contain more than 64 characters");
            _lasterrorcode = value;
        }
    }
    public virtual string LastErrorMessage
    {
        get { return _lasterrormessage; }
        set
        {
            if (value != null && value.Length > 1073741823)
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("value", value.ToString(), "LastErrorMessage cannot contain more than 1073741823 characters");
            _lasterrormessage = value;
        }
    }
}
```

I want to retrieve only few columns for one result for a given jobId (i didn't show all columns, too much ^^), so i use this :

```
var statRow = session.QueryOver<StatsRow>()
.Where(row => row.JobId == jobId)
.Select(
Projections.Property<StatsRow>(row => row.JobId),
Projections.Property<StatsRow>(row => row.JobState),
Projections.Property<StatsRow>(row => row.LastErrorCode),
Projections.Property<StatsRow>(row => row.LastErrorMessage),
Projections.Property<StatsRow>(row => row.CreationTime),
Projections.Property<StatsRow>(row => row.WorkflowName))
.TransformUsing(Transformers.AliasToBean<StatsRow>())
.SingleOrDefault<StatsRow>();
```

I checked if the returned values are correct, no pb (And the SQL query generated is correct too).
But, this snippet returns a StatsRow with default values and i don't know why. '^^ (i logged in the setters of the properties and NHibernate used it as well.)
If i use .SingleOrDefault() instead of (TransformUsing and SingleOrDefault), the values are the ones i want. So, is there any pb in the mapping ?

Is it possible to have a little help ? (by the way, sorry if i did some mistakes, english is not my main language ^^)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What we are missing here, is the `.WithAlias()` statement. So, expression like this:

```
Projections
   .Property<StatsRow>(row => row.JobId)
   .WithAlias(() => r.JobId),
```

will help `Transformer` to decide which projected *column* should be used for which *property*:

```
StatsRow r = null;

var statRow = session.QueryOver<StatsRow>()
.Where(row => row.JobId == jobId)
.Select(
  Projections.Property<StatsRow>(row => row.JobId).WithAlias(() => r.JobId),
  Projections.Property<StatsRow>(row => row.JobState).WithAlias(() => r.JobState),
  ...
)
.Take(1)
.TransformUsing(Transformers.AliasToBean<StatsRow>())
.SingleOrDefault<StatsRow>();
```

Comment: Ok, thanks, i will test later.
I saw use of Alias but i thought it is needed only when you have 2 entities (1 entity A is a property of an entity B and you need to map the properties of the entity A).
So, the properties specified in the projections are only for the query, the alias are needed for the transformer.